# Swift framework with OpenSSL-Universal Dependancy

Tags: ios, swift, openssl, frameworks, cocoapods

I am creating a Swift Framework that has OpenSSL-Universal Dependancy.
I have added it as a dependancy through cocopods as 'pod 'OpenSSL-Universal'

I want to be able to use it in my code after I use 'import OpenSSL' on top of the file.
But I get "no such module 'openssl'" error.

I checked the Pod folder for Open SSL Folder , It contains all the headers but not OpenSSL.Framework file as I have seen in other Pods that depend on it.

How to generate OpenSSL.Framework in the pod Folder ??
I got some scripts online but m not sure where to use them :(

Please Excuse me for being such a noob

Comment: Hi Juili. I have the same problem. Which file did produce the error 'No such module 'OpenSSL'? In my case it is a X509Wrapper.swift file. I would appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add the framework with

```
pod `OpenSSL-Universal/Framework`
```